# What language are road LED signs programmed in?

Tags: programming-languages

You know, these things. I assume they run on some old computer language/framework, anyone know what that might be?

[image]

Comment: The same one light bulbs are programmed in...

Comment: Related: http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01290/zombie_1290011c.jpg

Comment: Something must be running that parses text into LED arrays right?

Comment: Pretty sure the ones near me run on a Perl or PHP based system because, when they test them, the test strings look like $SOME_THING.  So, yeah, an old language :P

Comment: @jleedev, nemo not too helpful but seeing photos like that is what makes me wonder.

Comment: I ask because in Seattle right now they're testing this toll booth on a bridge and there are signs that are supposed to flash the time til downtown and price, or something to that effect, and while they've been testing it the signs have just been showing regular expressions of some sort. )$/) %/*/ etc. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displays themselves are pretty basic, they (in most cases) just have a microcontroller with some firmware that allows them to convert commands they get serially into patterns and/or characters.  The more recent ones also give feedback regarding broken LEDs for example.  Typically these firmwares are written either in assembly or C.

The real intelligence of these systems is often located in a central control system that coordinates an entire city or even a state.  These control systems can perform intelligent tasks on entire groups of signs like given the location of an accident, they add the correct distance to the accident to the warning message, automatically divert traffic, and so on.

I know of such systems written in C, C++, Java, G2, ... Depends on the moment they were designed.  So no, they're not by definition outdated and antique!  They do tend to have a longer lifespan than your average desktop app though which often leads to the oldest parts being swapped out for more recent developments and these newer modules will in many cases be based on more recent technologies.

Comment: Interesting. I never realized they were controlled remotely, I had heard there is a panel on the back (which still might also be the case). I think while maybe not antique, the software on these is probably not very up-to-date and well-maintained by the government (compared to desktop apps) so I think it'd be an interesting challenge to try to hack one like these zombie photos show.

Comment: Not surprising though, re: central control, if you think about it.

Comment: @artur these locally controlled panels also exist, and remotely controlled panels often have a local control panel with reduced functionality as well.  And as in any line of business there are good, security- and quality-conscious software companies and governments and bad, sloppy ones.